# How to get MOQ from the product by using object manager?

Tags: magento2, product, quantity

HI How can I get MOQ of product by using object manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($productId);
//print_r($productStockObj->getMinQty());
print_r($productStockObj->getData());
```

**You will get the output like below format**

```
Array
(
 [item_id] => 111
 [product_id] => 100
 [stock_id] => 1
 [qty] => 1000.0000
 [min_qty] => 10.0000
 [use_config_min_qty] => 0
 [is_qty_decimal] => 0
 [backorders] => 0
 [use_config_backorders] => 1
 [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
 [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
 [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
 [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
 [is_in_stock] => 1
 [low_stock_date] => 
 [notify_stock_qty] => 
 [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
 [manage_stock] => 1
 [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
 [stock_status_changed_auto] => 0
 [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
 [qty_increments] => 0.0000
 [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
 [enable_qty_increments] => 0
 [is_decimal_divided] => 0
 [website_id] => 1
 [deferred_stock_update] => 0
 [use_config_deferred_stock_update] => 1
 [type_id] => simple
)
```

Hope this helps you

Thanks ...